# Condicionales de caracteres y Enteros en C!

Tags: c

estoy intentando "EMULAR" un cajero automatico, y no se como a un if ponerle una doble condicion,q serian "el usuario" y "contraseña"

```
el codigo es el siguiente: 

 include < stdio .h >
 include < string. h>
 include < stdlib. h>

int main (){

float saldo;
char opc, usuario [10],resp_usu [5];
int saldo_mu = 3000,retiro;
int saldo_ca = 10000;
int dinero_dep,password;



printf (" Ingrese su usuario: ");
scanf ("%s" ,&usuario);
fflush( stdin );
printf (" Ingrese su password: ");
scanf ("%i" ,&password);
fflush( stdin );

if (strcmp (usuario, "ivan" ) && (password == 1 ) ==0){


do {
     printf ("\n\n A: Extrae dinero. \n\n B: Depositar dinero. \n\n C: Salir \n\n Indique una opcion: ");
      scanf("%c" ,&opc);
       fflush( stdin );
```

sigue,pero creo q con eso es suficiente.Gracias de antemano.

Comment: hola,sinceramente no se muy bien como funciona,a la primera le puse strcmp por q son caracteres y la segunda el == por q son numeros. la verdad noc si esta bien,por eso es q hice la pregunta ak! el codigo arranca,pero la segunda condicion no la toma como valida!

Comment: @IvanLeiva96 La condición correcta sería así: ```if (!strcmp (usuario, "ivan" ) && password == 1)``` La función strcmp devuelve 0 si ambas cadenas son iguales, de lo contrario -1.

Comment: ok muchas gracias,disculpas las molestias!

Comment: Si esta pregunta ya no tiene sentido, por favor, elimínala

Answer (score 1):

Primero, los tipos booleanos en C no existen. Para establecer una condición, lo que hace C es utilizar los tipos de datos enteros como booleanos, siendo 0 el valor falso y cualquier otro número verdadero.

La función strcmp tiene la siguiente definición:

```
int strcmp( char* cadena1, char* cadena2)
```

y lo que hace es recibir dos cadenas (cadena1 y cadena2), las compara y devuelve un entero. Lo que está haciendo realmente es restar las cadenas (mediante un algoritmo interno) y devuelve el valor. Si ambas cadenas son iguales, el valor de retorno es 0, en el caso que la primera sea mayor devuelve un número positivo y en el caso de que cadena2 sea mayor que cadena1 devuelve un número negativo.

En tu caso especifico, y considerando lo anterior,

```
if ( (strcmp(usuario, "ivan")  == 0) && (password == 1) )
```

Con el usuario "ivan" y la constraseña 1.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta.Valoro mucho el tiempo q te tomaste. Un saludo!